# Magento 2 ProductCollection and ProductRepository not loading all products rows

Tags: magento2, products

- I'm trying to load all products.
- `catalog_product_entity` has 3478 rows.
- Loading all products though collection or through repository ends up with 2418 products.
- I also tried paginating the collection, same result

Loading through collection

```
$products = $this->productCollectionFactory->create()->getItems();
var_dump(count($products)); // output 2418
exit;
```

Loading products through repository

```
$criteria = $this->searchCriteriaBuilder->create();
$products = $this->productRepository->getList($criteria)->getItems();
var_dump(count($products)); // output 2418
```

- Why aren't the other ~ 1k products loading?
- What could be the problem?
- How to debug?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All the products that were not loading were disabled.

Also there is an known issue in 2.2.* that disabled products can not be loaded using the product collection.

https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/13411